# Perl user input file searching

Tags: file, perl, io

I am currently trying to take user input in for a file name and then search for that file. The program has to terminate gracefully if it isn't found and then continue if it is. For some reason from the research I found, the "-e" function isn't working for me. I am on a mac if that makes a difference although I have the shabang.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;


print "Enter the name of a file: ";
my $userInput = <STDIN>;
my $fileName = '/' . $userInput;

if(-e $fileName) {
  print "File exist.\n";
  die();
} else {
  print "File doesnt exist.\n";
  die();
}
```

Never ends up finding the file if it is named right or not.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are also getting the newline as part of the filename when you hit enter key. You can notice that if you print `$filename`

You can get rid of it by using `chomp` function after getting the input:

`chomp($userInput);`

Also, I'm not sure if you actually want to check for the file in the root directory or in current directory. If it is in the current maybe you missed a dot before the slash:
`'./' . $userInput;`

With this two changes your code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;


print "Enter the name of a file: ";
my $userInput = <STDIN>;
chomp($userInput);
my $fileName = './' . $userInput;

if(-e $fileName) {
  print "File '$fileName' exist.\n";
  die();
} else {
  print "File '$fileName' doesnt exist.\n";
  die();
}
```

Comment: I added the line my $fileName = './'.chomp($userInput); but it still goes into the else part of the if statement if I when I do the -e part

Comment: That is not the same because you are appending the chomp function return value. Add the code I mentioned as a new line right after you get the user input.

Comment: You can make your print statements show the file name so it is more obvious what is happening `print "File '$fileName' doesnt exist.\n";` for example

Comment: When I do "-e './file.txt' I get a match but when I use fileName I don't so I figured the text are not the same so when I compare them in a if statement my suspicions were true. Even after I chomp userInput or fileName they don't. Im not sure why.

Comment: Have you also changed the line I mentioned about the dot before the slash when building the path? I'll edit the answer with how the code should look like

Comment: @SantiagoBruno Note that prepending `./` is a no-op (unless `$userInput` itself starts with a slash).

Comment: @melpomene the original code prepended only `/` so it would look for files only in the filesystem root.

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is you can just remove that code and do `my $fileName = $userInput;` (or get rid of the extra variable).

Comment: The issue seemed to be that I was chomping userInput in the same statement where I initiate fileName. Or at least that is what I had to change in order to get mine to work which is weird because I tried this before posting my first response. Thanks very much.

Comment: @motherloadmining You can do it in the same statement: `chomp(my $userInput = readline STDIN);`